# Move deleted record to another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to move deleted record from one table to another table but I am getting this error.

> ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DBO.TRIGGER_ON_ABCD
  ON DBO.ABCD
  INSTEAD OF DELETE
  AS
  BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT DBO.XYZ(COLS) SELECT COLS FROM DELETED;

  DELETE T FROM DBO.ABCD AS T 
  INNER JOIN DELETED AS D
  ON T.KEY_COLUMN=D.KEY_COLUMN;
  END
  GO
```

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) did you find `set nocount`? And do you actually **have** a table named `deleted`

Comment: No i don't have a  'deleted' table. Actually i am learning how to do it..describe where i am wrong..

Comment: Then how do you excpect `inner join deleted` to work?

Comment: i CREATED DELETED TABLE BUT STILL ITS GIVING ME **ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword** . can you suggest a query how t do it..

Answer (score 1):

First, `INSTEAD OF` triggers can only be created on `VIEW`s. Second, why even try `INSTEAD OF`? You really want the row to be deleted, so let it be. All you want from the trigger is the insert into the other table.

```
SQL> create table t(a,b,c) as select dummy, dummy, dummy from dual;

SQL> create table u as select * from t where 1=0;

SQL> create or replace trigger t_del
  2  before delete on t
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into u values(:OLD.a, :OLD.b, :OLD.c);
  6  end t_del;
  7  /

SQL> select 'Count of T' " ", count(*) cnt from t
  2  union all
  3  select 'Count of U', count(*) from u;

                  CNT
---------- ----------
Count of T          1
Count of U          0

SQL> delete from t;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select 'Count of T' " ", count(*) cnt from t
  2  union all
  3  select 'Count of U', count(*) from u;

                  CNT
---------- ----------
Count of T          0
Count of U          1
```